# Why My RecyclerView adapter does not work?

Tags: android

Please, anyone follow my code and find the mistake in my adapter. It shows no data.

This is my adapter code. I have followed a tutorial but it does not work and I don't know why.

```
 public class SportAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SportAdapter .MyViewHolder> {

    List<SportModel> SportModelList;
    Context context;

    public SportAdapter (List<SportModel> sportModels ,  Context context) {
        SportModelList= sportModels ;
        this.context = context;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.sport_item, parent, false);

        return new deviceAdapter.MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final SportModel sportModel = SportModel.get(position);
        holder.SportName.setText(sportModel.getSportName());

    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0 ;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView SportName;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            SportName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sport_name);

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Change `getItemCount` to return `SportModelList.size();` instead of 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add this `SportModelList.size` in  `getItemCount`

```
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return SportModelList.size();
    }
```